# How can you cumulate the values of a binominal distribution in Rstudio?

Tags: r, statistics

```
dbinom(5, size=7, prob=0.3) +
dbinom(6, size=7, prob=0.3) +
dbinom(7, size=7, prob=0.3)
```

`pbinom( 5, size = 7, prob= 0.3)`

How do you get the same value for pbinom as in the cumulated answers in dbinom?

Comment: ok, then I guess you know the answer

Comment: Not really, You get the same answer all the time but why doesn't the pbinom , which is a cumulative function doesn't give the same as all the dbinoms added up?

Comment: Yes it does: `pbinom(5, size = 7, prob= 0.3);sum(dbinom(0:5, size = 7, prob= 0.3))`.

Comment: pbinom(5, ......) is the sum of dbinom(x, .;....) for x going from 0 to 5.

Comment: you need `pbinom(4,7,0.3,lower.tail=FALSE)` OR `1-pbinom(4,7,0.3)`

Comment: Well, thank you for the answers. I found it now!